# Flutter carousel pro image cache How to

Tags: dart, flutter, carousel

I'm able to load images into Carousel (carousel_pro) using NetworkImage, but using AdvancedNetworkImage throws the error: type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'ImageProvider'

```
{
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 0.9,
                child: Carousel(
                  images: snapshot["images"].map((url){
                    return Image(
                      image: AdvancedNetworkImage(url, useDiskCache: true));
                  }).toList(),
                  dotSize: 4.0,
                  dotSpacing: 15.0,
                  dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
                  dotColor: Colors.red,
                  autoplay: false,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
```

Could any please enlighten me how to solve this, I mean caching the images that load in the Carousel?

Comment: [NetworkImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/NetworkImage-class.html) docs says: "The image will be cached regardless of cache headers from the server.". Do you need a more fine grained caching?

Comment: Well, if I put the emulator in airplane mode, images loaded with NetworkImage do not show up. That's why I switched to AdvancedNetworkImage.

Comment: Also tried with CachedNetworkImageProvider. I just want the images to load from cache when the network is down and also speed up subsequent loadtimes by loading from cache.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved it by changing return Image(image: AdvancedNetworkImage(url, useDiskCache: true)); to return CachedNetworkImage(url);